# How to extract text.text information using regular expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a following sample string

```
ptv.test foo bar cc.any more words
```

I want a regular expression which can extract the patter text.text. For example in above string it should match `ptv.test` and `cc.any`

Thanks

Comment: `[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+`? Or `[a-z]+\.[a-z]+` if no uppercase letters are allowed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696921/c-sharp-regex-to-match-the-word-with-dot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
string s = "ptv.test foo bar cc.any more words";
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"\w+\.\w+");

foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Which outputs:

> ptv.test
>
> cc.any

Answer (score 2):

```
\w+\.\w+
```

(one or more word characters, the period, one or more word characters)

Answer (score 1):

`[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]`

You need to escape the period becuase it is a Regex special character that matches anything

Answer (score 0):

Your question is *vague* one. The answer depends on what does the "text" actually mean. Some possibilities are below:

```
 [a-z]+\.[a-z]+       English lower case letters a..z
 [A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+ English letters A..Z or a..z
 \p{L}+\.\p{L}+       Any unicode letters
 \w+\.\w+             Any word symbols (letters + digits)
 ...
```

Another detail to concern with is should "text" be preceded / followed by *white spaces* or string start/end. E.g. for given

```
 pt???v.test foo bar cc.an!!!y more words
```

should `"v.test"` or `"cc.an"` be considered as matches. If not, add `\b` before and after the required pattern, e.g.:

```
 \b[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\b
```

The implementation can be something like this:

```
 string source = @"ptv.test foo bar cc.any more words";

 string pattern = @"\b[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\b";

 string[] matches = Regex
   .Matches(source, pattern)
   .Cast<Match>()
   .Select(match => match.Value)
   .ToArray(); // let's organize matches as an array

 // ptv.test
 // cc.any
 Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, matches));
```