# Remove word that ends with a period

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use regex to remove a word that ends with a period.

I want to only remove `Ep.` as a whole word, but not if it's part of another word.

Also I will use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`.

---

> This Ep. is 01. TestEp.01Test.

Should be:

> This is 01. TestEp.01Test.

---

I thought it should be `\b(Ep\.)\b` but it doesn't work.

https://regex101.com/r/QcOiMR/2/

---

I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/5696940/6806643

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `\b(Ep\.)\B`, because the period is not a "word" character but a "non-word" character and as such, you need a "non-word boundary" (`\B`) and not a "word boundary" (`\b`).